# pyinstallerで作成したexeファイルが起動しない

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5を使って作ったGUIをpyinstallerでexeファイルに直してみました。できたexeファイルを起動しようとすると、

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "". Reinstalling the applicaton may fix this problem.
```

と出力され、起動しません。どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: 同じエラーメッセージが出力されているようですが、これらのページは見ましたか？

https://qiita.com/umechan47/items/662cc7f8d08b417f9461

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040630/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-cx-freeze-exe-pyth

Comment: 私なりに解決策を探したつもりだったのですがそんなページがあったんですね。おかげ様で無事exeファイルに直すことができました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

必要なpluginが実行ファイルと同じフォルダ内に入っていないとダメなようです。pluginはpyinstallerでexe化する際にファイルを一つにまとめないように(--onefileをかかない)するとできるPyQt5というフォルダの中に入っていました。